# Weak version of (elliptic analog) Artin's primitive roots conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve, and $P\in E(\mathbb{Q})$ be any non-torsion point. Given any $\varepsilon>0,$ how often it is true that $\mathrm{ord}(P \pmod p)>p^{1-\varepsilon},~p~\mathrm{prime}$?

Artin's primitive root conjecture asks for the proportion of primes $p$ for which $\mathrm{ord}(P \pmod p)=\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)\sim p$. We are asking for a weaker version here. It is easy to obtain a lower bound with exponent $1/3-\varepsilon$ for almost all primes $p$. However, I am not able to get by the desired exponent. What are the known results related to my question? Let me point out, [https://www.cs.uleth.ca/~akbary/lt_revision.pdf](https://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Eakbary/lt_revision.pdf) shows that the exponent can be achieved if we work with $\# \Gamma \pmod p$, for some $\Gamma\subseteq E(\mathbb{Q})$ with large enough rank (under AHC and GRH).